# How to install flash player on ubuntu unity

Tags: unity, software-center, flash, steam, minecraft

Ok ive landed myself in quite the prediciment. I got a chromebook from my school and my robotics teacher noticed i was very good with computers. So he made a deal with me. He came up with challenges for me and said that i wont get into any trouble at my school. One was to disable all administrative monitoring etc... I completed all of them with ease but my latest test is to download software to a chromebook we agreed on like steam or minecraft.
I managed to figure out that you have to be in linux in order to install software and well... im a n00b when it comes to linux all the branches of it and what not. And i need help im running 32 bit on unity ubuntu 12.04 i believe.there is no flash player in the software center. and iv tried a ton of code in terminal and none of them worked. If someone could help me to install it along with how to get minecraft or install steam on this that would be amazing. a step by step intro and im willing to do anything even power wash to get it
-thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```